# Base64 decode and unzip to string (Java 7)

Tags: xml, base64, zip, java-7

I am struggling with the following any would appreciate any advise. I do a webservice call and in the return data is a return string. To get the data from this string i need to do the following.

1. Decode the result string via Base64
2. The decode value will be in a PK zip format.
3. Extract the Zip contents to expose the resulting XML block.

In my java action i struggle to get the decoded base64 string into zip format and then to unzip. And if possible get away from creating files and just work with the streams.
Thanks in advance

Comment: have you tried anything?

Comment: As you are using Java 7 you might want to have a look at [Apaches Base64 class](https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-codec/apidocs/org/apache/commons/codec/binary/Base64.html) and for turning the converted bytes into an in-memory Zip archive have a look at this [Java's ZipInputStream](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/zip/ZipInputStream.html). Once you have the `ZipInputStream` in place you can iterate through its content with `zis.getNextEntry()`